# How can I serialize and communicate ActiveRecord instances across identical Rails apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, serialization

The main idea is that I have several worker instances of a Rails app, and then a main aggregate

I want to do something like this with the following pseudo pseudo-code

```
posts = Post.all.to_json( :include => { :comments => { :include => :blah } })
# send data to another, identical, exactly the same Rails app

# ...
# Fast forward to the separate but identical Rails app:
# ...

# remote_posts is the posts results from the first Rails app
posts = JSON.parse(remote_posts)  
posts.each do |post|
  p = Post.new
  p = post
  p.save
end
```

---

I'm shying away from Active Resource because I have thousands of records to create, which would mean thousands of requests for each record. Unless there is a way to do it all in one request with Active Resource that is simple, I'd like to avoid it.

- Format doesn't matter. Whatever makes it convenient.
- The IDs don't need to be sent, because the other app will just be creating records and assigning new IDs in the "aggregate" system.
- The hierarchy would need to be preserved (E.g. "Hey other Rails app, I have genres, and each genre has an artist, and each artist has an album, and each album has songs" etc.)

Comment: Is there a reason both applications can't share a database, and thus both have access to the same data?

Comment: Well, to be honest, because it seems taboo to integrate databases, and these databases are on different networks, but I don't know if I want to have the web server's database listen on anything but local ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options you could implement to get this to work:

### **Active Resource**

As others have answered, you could make use of [ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html).  After reading your comments, this seems like a solution you'd like to steer clear of due to the multiple-request aspect

### **Receiving Controller**

You could have a controller in your second rails application that receives data and creates records out of it.

```
class RecordReceiver < ActiveRecord::Base
  def create
    params[:data][:posts].each do |p|
      Post.create(p)
    end
  end
end
```

You could namespace this controller inside an "API" namespace, which is a rather clean solution if implemented properly.

### **Share the Database**

You could share one database across two applications.  This means you won't need to send the data from one model to another, it will already be there.  This is the least amount of work for you as a developer, but may not be possible depending on the system architecture you have.

### **Two databases in each application**

You could implement multiple database in each application, like so:

```
#Add to database.yml
other_development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: otherdb_development
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

other_production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: otherdb_production
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
```

Then, define your models like so:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class PostClone < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "other_#{RAILS_ENV}"
end
```

Now, your `Clone` model will point to the current database, and the `PostClone` model will point to the other database.  With access to both, you can copy the data over whenever you need to with basic model methods.

### **Conclusion**

Since you don't want to use ActiveResource, I would recommend that you simply share the database between the applications.  If this isn't a possibility, then try having two models, each going to a different database.  Finally, the receiving controller is a valid, albeit slower option (as it needs to do the HTTP request on top of the database requests)

Answer (score 3):

Use [active resource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html) to directly create your posts in the remote app.

http://railscasts.com/tags/19

Comment: I'd much rather like to serialize the data and send it over as one HTTP request as I have thousands of records to send to another Rails app.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer, but couple of ideas:

- Instead of your `to_json`, you can call `Marshal.dump` with your posts.
- You can create a controller which would receive such serialized data through HTTP on remote rails instance, `Marshal.load` and save them (probably with some code to solve all kinds of collisions).

I'm not sure how marshaling would handle included data and how much work would be needed on remote side to ensure clean importing (what about records which would break some uniqueness etc), but I'd experiment a bit and see.

BTW, Since you asked the question in the first place, I guess standard database replication solutions don't work for you?

Comment: I haven't looked into replication on the database end (I use MySQL) but I would use it if it was simple enough. I've used Active Resource, but things weren't being created on the remote end for reasons I did not know, so I got discouraged and gave up on it. At my job they use files for a lot of things, so I figured serialization might be the way to go.

Comment: Also, there would definitely be ID collisions, so the ID can be chucked out the window when the records are sent over the wire. I basically want to serialize the attributes, so that they can all be created at once when Rails receives them, and preserve the hierarchy (e.g. genres => artists => albums => songs)

Comment: Yup, I already mentioned "solving all kinds of collisions". I didn't know about ActiveResource, it indeed looks as a better way to solve this. But I'd take a look at database replication based solution first anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar use case and I use **ActiveResource**. If you want to preserve the contained objects this is a good choice. ActiveResource gives you a choice of JSON or XML as the wire format.

You can pack all your records in one request. At the receiving end you can process the request in one transaction.

**Source App**

```
  class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def synch
      @posts = Post.all(:conditions => {...})
      #
      # Multiple posts and their child objects uploaded in one HTTP call.
      #
      Remote::Post.upload(@posts)                       
    end
  end

  # ActiveResource model for remote Post
  module Remote
    class Post < ActiveResource::Base
      self.site = "http://host:3000/"
      def self.upload posts
        # pass :include option to to_xml to select
        # hierarchy.
        body = posts.to_xml(:root => 'posts', :except => [:id]
                 :include => { :genres =>{ :except => [:id],
                                 :artists => { :except => [:id],
                                    :albums => { :except => [:id],
                                       :songs => {:except => [:id] }
                                    }
                                 }
                               }
                             }
        )
        post(:upload, {}, body) 
      end
    end
  end
```

**Destination App**

```
  class PostsController < ApplicationController  
    def upload
      #
      # Multiple posts and their child objects are saved in one call.
      #
      Posts.create(params[:posts])                                    
    end
  end

  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :genres
    accepts_nested_attributes_for ::genres
  end

  class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :artists 
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :artists 
  end

  class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :songs
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :songs
  end

  class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :albums
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :albums
  end


  class Songs < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
```

Other options for faster processing at the destination is [ARExtensions](http://github.com/zdennis/ar-extensions/tree/master/ar-extensions/). This gem supports bulk inserts.

**Destination Route**

```
map.resources :posts, :collection => { :upload => :post }
```

Comment: Hmm... looks like it might be worth a try.

Comment: I have added additional information about routes, which I missed in my original answer.